# Adding a subdomain to htaccess file in AWS lightsail LAMP

Tags: amazon-web-services, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, lamp, amazon-lightsail

I am using AWS Lightsail LAMP instance for hosting the site.
I want to add subdomain to it.After searching a lot, i couldn't fix it myself and need some help.

**Details:**

Root domain --> English  -https://www.example.site/

I want to add other languages as subdomain.

Sub domain - French  -https://fr.example.site/
sub domain - German  -https://de.example.site/

I have completed the vhost configuration and the apache2 server is serving the test pages succesfully from https://fr.example.site/ and https://de.example.site/

However, when i deploy the actual application with htaccess, the root domain works fine, but subdomain results in the below Error

```
fr.example.site is currently unable to handle this request. 
HTTP ERROR 500
```

There is some issues with my htaccess rules.

Here is my existing htaccess content.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]


RewriteRule ^index.html$ index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)-result.html$ result.php
RewriteRule ^2-letter-words-with-(.*).html$ twoletter.php
RewriteRule ^3-letter-words-with-(.*).html$ threeletter.php
RewriteRule ^words-starting-in-(.*).html$ wordstartedwith.php
```

I want to add the rules for subdomain fr and de so the contents are served from the below directories.

https://www.example.site/  --> /home/bitnami/htdocs/
https://fr.example.site/  --> /home/bitnami/htdocs/fr
https://de.example.site/  --> /home/bitnami/htdocs/de

Any pointers will be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
##For base site Rules.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)example\.site [NC]
RewriteCond ^/?$
RewriteRule ^ home/bitnami/htdocs/ [L]

##For fr site Rules.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} fr\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond ^/?$
RewriteRule ^ home/bitnami/htdocs/fr [L]

##For de site Rules.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} de\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond ^/?$
RewriteRule ^ home/bitnami/htdocs/de [L]
```

Comment: Hey Ravi , i replaced the contents of the htaccess file, however,  it errors out saying "HTTP ERROR 500"

Comment: Hey Ravi , i replaced the contents of the htaccess file, however,  it errors out saying "HTTP ERROR 500" .   HEre is the live site name : https://wordsquick.site/ , https://fr.wordsquick.site/  , https://de.wordsquick.site/

Comment: @tamilrain, could you please do let me know if you have changed example.com with your wordsquick.site in my rules?

Comment: Yes Ravi, i did replaced the placeholder with the actual site name along with the extension (example.com with wordsquick.site)

Comment: @tamilrain, ok, I have fixed the Rules now, could you please check them now and let me know how it goes?